# can i multiple join without createbuilder in nestjs?

Tags: database, join, backend, nestjs, typeorm

I tried to join three tables,

but I couldn't find an example using `relations:[].`

I used to solve it using `createbuilder`, but I wonder if there is an example.

```
    const info = await this.aRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('a')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('a.bs', 'b')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('b.cs', 'c')
      .where('a.id = :id', { id: id })
      .getOne();
```

Is there a hint that I can find?

Comment: Can you show some of your code about what you achieve so far ?

Comment: The "relations: []" would be enough to get several relations in the query using repository pattern in typeorm. But  we need to see the code to solve your problem, here is some example with relations in the typeorm docs https://typeorm.io/#/find-options

Comment: oh, I attached my code now

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 const info = await this.aRepo.findOne(id, {
      relations: [
        "bs",
        "cs"
      ]
  })
```

But make sure your relations property is right set up, if not the relations won't work.